# How to simplify logical expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, logic

I would like to simplify

```
(a == c && c != 0) || (a == 0 && c == 0)
```

to

```
a == c
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
Reduce[(a==c&&c!=0)||(a==0&&c==0),Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting. Why Reduce[(a==c&&c!=0)||(a==0&&c==0),Complexes] doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Not assuming `a,c \[Element] Reals`,

```
Solve[(a == c && c != 0) || (a == 0 && c == 0), c] // FullSimplify
```

> `{{c -> a}}`

and

```
 Solve[(a == c && c != 0) || (a == 0 && c == 0), a] // FullSimplify
```

> `{{a -> c}}`